# Does cypress support database queries execution

Tags: cypress

My testing is purely DB queries validation in sql server and need to do automate sql queries.
I am wondering Cypress will support or not .
If yes please get me more information.

Comment: Is there any Cypress documentation? What does that state, what more do you need?

Comment: Please also provide information on what you have tried and where you looked to give more context. Eg - I want to automate queries, but i tried by doing X,Y as per [tutorial link] but it did not work And post the error if any

Comment: agree with @Aditya first you have to establish a connection to DB then you will be able to do DB queries some examples I found [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3689) for you)))